# How can I add a destination in between others, on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

How can I add something [at the orange arrow](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Greenwich,+Prince+Edward+Island+National+Park,+Saint+Peters+Bay,+PE+C0A+2A0/Hopewell+Rocks+Park,+Hopewell+Cape,+New+Brunswick/Lunenburg,+NS/Halifax,+Nova+Scotia/Cape+Breton+Highlands+National+Park,+Nova+Scotia/@45.5355972,-64.9622883,7z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m32!4m31!1m5!1m1!1s0x4b5e307f943f9575:0xfd191624847e5551!2m2!1d-62.703239!2d46.4460482!1m5!1m1!1s0x4b5f5537e6cea179:0x98d8a718a0d196ff!2m2!1d-64.576006!2d45.823182!1m5!1m1!1s0x4b575bc120aed143:0x56397a4fad304deb!2m2!1d-64.3188354!2d44.3770053!1m5!1m1!1s0x4b5a211407dbfac1:0x666be3a6438b2ddc!2m2!1d-63.5753196!2d44.6488625!1m5!1m1!1s0x4b6703aed8386e5f:0x553f94c3cb08c2d3!2m2!1d-60.6509771!2d46.7382854!3e0)? It'd be too inefficient to delete everything under Greenwich, add the missing destination, and retype everything under Greenwich? See beneath.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- add your destination via: **+ Add destination**
- drag & drop your entry where you want it using triple dots

[image]